# c# 'string.Equals' returning wrong results?

Tags: c#, assert

first time poster so forgive me if my formatting is off or anything :)

I'm working on my game engine in C# using XNA but when I check the name of a new node against existing nodes, the Assert fires off unpredictably even when there is no matching name in the list. Here is the code I'm referring too:

```
    public void CheckNameIsUnique(string cName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_aNodeList.Count; ++i)
        {
            Debug.Assert(m_aNodeList[i].GetName().Equals(cName),
                "USE OF NON-UNIQUE NAME: " + cName);
        }
    }
```

The assert will fire off -for example- when checking, "box1" and the only node in the list has the name "RootNode".

I get the same unpredictable results using: 
`string == string` and `string.CompareTo(string) > 0`

Any ideas? =\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assert is supposed to make sure the condition is TRUE. If it's false the assert will fail.
What you want is to assert that it's NOT equal. use != and it should be fine.

Comment: I was in a hurry when I made my last comment, so to elaborate a little now, I was feeling VERY stupid when you pointed out my miss use of Assert.. As I had been using it successfully all day >.> I guess my brain just shut off for a while there haha. Again, many thanks.

Comment: I guess taking breaks at the right time is also a skill we need to learn :). Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 3):

The assertion fires if the condition is *false*.  You have your conditional backwards.  See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63efys0.aspx